# What is the difference between "struct *Stack stack" and "struct Stack* stack"?

Tags: c++, c

While writing a code when I am writing `struct *Stack stack` then code is not working and when I am writing it like `struct Stack* stack` code is working,can someone tell me the difference between these two code?

Comment: Well the main difference is that the first one is not valid C++...

Comment: The syntax is different. The second declares a pointer to `struct Stack` called `stack`, the first is invalid. The reason it's invalid is that it doesn't fit the grammar of either language, c or c++.

Comment: First is invalid in C and C++.

Comment: In c++ use `Stack* stack` instead. The `struct` is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

> While writing a code when I am writing struct *Stack stack then code is not working

This is because `struct *Stack stack` is not correct syntax. This would imply a pointer named `Stack stack`, which is not a valid name, pointing to a `struct`, which is not valid in [c](/questions/tagged/c) or [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), as you have to indicate what type of `struct` your pointer will be pointing to. The word `struct` is not standalone.

> when I am writing it like struct Stack* stack code is working

On the other hand, the declaration :

```
struct Stack* stack;
```

implies a pointer named `stack` which points to a `struct Stack` (which you have defined somewhere).